# Tkinter: switching between frames using Canvas (content from the second frame just overlies the first one)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

i really hope that somebody can help me in this because time is literally running out :/
thanks so much for **any help** provided!

1. my main goal is to have a frame within a main window and in that frame there should be some widgets
2. i want to have a button so i can switch between widgets/content in that same frame. my problem is that if i press the button the background of the frame turns to grey and i have both the first and the second content displayed at the same time (like it just overlies the first content).. and if i press the button another time it doesn't return solely to the first content.
3. the background_image should always stay the same during skipping.

i have the following code (and more .. but skipped some widgets for this).
if you need further information pls let me know!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import date, datetime
import time
import calendar


def create_content():
   
    def digital_clock():
        time_live = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        my_canvas1.itemconfig("my_clock", text=time_live)
        my_canvas1.after(200, digital_clock)

    digital_clock()
    my_canvas1.create_text(400, 60, text=' ', font=("Helvetica", 30, "bold"), fill="white", tags="my_clock")

    
    date_add_text = str(date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y"))

    my_canvas1.create_text(150, 60, text=date_add_text, font=("Helvetica", 30, "bold"), fill="white")


def change_frame():
    
    backgroundimage2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Backgroundimage_cropped.png")

    my_canvas1.itemconfig(image_on_canvas1, image=backgroundimage2)

    def get_calender():
        date = datetime.now()
        actual_year = int(date.strftime("%Y"))
        actual_month = int(date.strftime("%m"))

        cal = calendar.LocaleTextCalendar(locale='de_DE.utf8')

        calender = cal.formatmonth(actual_year, actual_month, 4, 2)

        return calender

    result = get_calender()
    my_canvas1.create_text(10, 10, text=result, font=("Helvetica", 20), fill="white", anchor="nw")

    button1.configure(text="zurück zur Übersicht", command=create_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main_window = tk.Tk()
    main_window.title("main window")
    main_window.geometry("1000x800")
    main_window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    backgroundimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="Backgroundimage.png")

    my_canvas = tk.Canvas(main_window, width=1000, height=800, highlightthickness=0)
    my_canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=backgroundimage, anchor="nw")

    my_canvas.create_text(500, 50, text="Mein Kalender", font=("Helvetica", 40), fill="white")

    backgroundimage2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Backgroundimage_cropped.png")

    
    button1 = ttk.Button(main_window, text="Gesamter Kalender", command=change_frame, cursor="hand2")
    button1_window = my_canvas.create_window(840, 10, anchor="nw", window=button1)

    first_frame = tk.Frame(main_window, width=800, height=660)
    first_frame.configure(highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=4)
    first_frame.place(x=100, y=90, width=800, height=660)

    my_canvas1 = tk.Canvas(first_frame, width=800, height=660, highlightthickness=0)
    my_canvas1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    image_on_canvas1 = my_canvas1.create_image(0, 0, image=backgroundimage2, anchor="nw")

    create_content()

    tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have not asked a question

Answer (score 0):

I actually came across the ame problem to fix it change `backgroundimage2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="Backgroundimage_cropped.png")` to a global variable, if you dont it makes it just a white or grey screen